# Test Flutter on Android 5.01

Tags: android, flutter, debugging

I want to test my flutter app on a real device. For that I use an old Samsung s4 with android 5.0.1.
USB-Debugging is enabled.
When I want to debug my app on this device (with a usb-cabel) I got this error:

```
The client closed with pending request "_flutter.listViews".
```

The app works fine in the emulator on my pc.

**Flutter doctor:**

```
[√] Flutter (Channel beta, 1.25.0-8.2.pre, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1316], locale de DE)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
[√] VS Code (version 1.52.1)
[√] Connected device (3 available)

• No issues found!
```

**build-gradle:**

```
minSdkVersion 16
```

Comment: What is your environment sdk in pubspec file?

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that you have run through all the steps required to setup flutter for Android Development.
https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/flutter-for/android-devs

Second make sure that you have the SDK required for Android 5.0.1 and above installed on your machine. You can run do this through **Android Studio -> Sdk Manager -> Install Required SDKs and Accept Licences.**

Third, make sure that you can successfully deploy to iOS, then if that works you can assume that there is no issue with the flutter code.
Please try to switch to the stable channel and try another deployment.

If the client connection is closing, then it means that there is a startup crash, however it sounds like the apk is being installed on your device.
You will have to run this on Android Studio and check your logcat as to why the watchdog is closing the application. Once you get these logs, please post them again here, and we will continue.

Comment: I have installed he SDKs for android 5.0 and 5.1.
In this moment I am not able to test it in iOS. I hope later.
When I want to run the app in the logcat are following errors:

01-18 16:02:39.401 3531-3531/? E/Diag_Lib:  Diag_LSM_Init: Failed to open handle to diag driver, error = 2
01-18 16:02:40.171 3506-3506/? E/SMD: smd Interface open failed errno is 2 -1